# Bootstrap less - combine container & row into one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This might be a stupid question, due to my lack of less/bootstrap understanding, but is it possible to somehow combine, through less, .container & .row into one, so I just have to write `<div class="myCalss"></div>`
instead of `<div class="container"><div class="row">...</div></div>`.

Background: I have to website where I use container fixed, but with sections with different colors. So I have to write a lot of `<div class=”container”><div class=”row”>…` .

I hope it makes sense.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNqNJx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the mixin.less and grid.less into your less file then call the .container() from the grid.less and .makerow() from the mixin.less. Sample code below.

```
@import (reference) "bootstrap/grid.less";
@import (reference) "bootstrap/mixins.less";

.wrapper{
  .container();
  .make-row();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, I just had to add a reference to variables as well (@import (reference) "bootstrap/variables.less";).